# warning: unreachable code in Scala repl

Tags: scala

**this code is in "scale-exercises.org" site**

```
class Car(val make: String, val model: String, val year: Short, val topSpeed: Short)
class Employee(val firstName: String, val middleName: Option[String], val lastName: String)

object Tokenizer {
  def unapply(x: Car) = Some(x.make, x.model, x.year, x.topSpeed)

  def unapply(x: Employee) = Some(x.firstName, x.lastName)
}

val result = new Employee("Kurt", None, "Vonnegut") match {
  case Tokenizer(c, d) ⇒ "c: %s, d: %s".format(c, d)
  case _ ⇒ "Not found"
}
```

return : **warning: unreachable code
         case _ ⇒ "Not found"**

**why is warning code ?? please reply ...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `unapply`'s return type is `Some`, Scala knows that the match will never fail and the subsequent cases can never be reached.

If you explicitly declare the return type as `Option`, the warning will disappear, but that won't change the fact that the `case _` can never actually be reached.

Comment: I don't understand. can you show me the code about explicitly code as type is Option ?

Comment: @이창언 Do you understand that the `case _ => "Not found"` can never actually be reached? If not, can you describe a circumstance, under which you think it should be reached?

Comment: I got it. these code will never fail. thank you so much. this is my mistake

Comment: @이창언 Regarding the type, I meant `def unapply(x: Employee): Option[(String, String)] = ...`. Again, that won't change the fact that the case can never be reached, but it will hide this fact from the compiler.